# display max age and min age in controller

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, custom-controller

I have a requirement where age need to be displayed on vf page through wrapper class,I am able to display age in vf page.

wrapper class :

```
    public class Contactwrapper{

          public Decimal Age{get;set;}

    }

 for(Contact c: [SELECT Id, Name , Age__c, FROM Contact where ID = :ID]) {
          Contactwrapper contwrapper = new Contactwrapper();
          contwrapper.Age = c.Age__c;
          contactList.add(contwrapper);
```

Visualforce Page

```
apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="c" id="table">
             <apex:column headerValue="Include" >
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" />
             </apex:column>
               <apex:column value="{!c.Age}" HeaderValue="Age" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Now I have Max age and min age in one object X.I want the age which got from wrapper class need to be displayed as min age and max age . Any suggestions

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi anjali, please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. As written, this post does not really make clear what steps you have taken to try to solve this problem, and why they did not work for you. The more specific you are about these things, the more likely the community will react positively to your question and help you find the answer.

Comment: Do you realize the query you've included in your question can only possibly return exactly one record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you use some other query on the `Contact` object which can actually return multiple records. First step would be to add these data points as properties on your controller/extension:

```
public Decimal minAge { get; private set; }
public Decimal maxAge { get; private set; }
```

If these two data points are all you care about in regards to these `Contact` records, then you can use aggregate queries:

```
AggregateResult aggregate = [
    SELECT MIN(Age__c) minAge, MAX(Age__c) maxAge
    FROM Contact WHERE ...
];
minAge = (Decimal)aggregate.get('minAge');
maxAge = (Decimal)aggregate.get('maxAge');
```

If you care about other data on the individual records, you can just add these properties and sort a `List<Decimal>` to get the first and last values:

```
List<Decimal> ages = new List<Decimal>();
for (Contact record : [/*query*/])
{
    if (record.Age__c != null)
        ages.add(record.Age__c);
    // any additional logic
}
ages.sort();
minAge = ages[0];
maxAge = ages[ages.size() - 1];
```